# Crash issue when setting setCenterWindow + NappDrawer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a problem when setting center window with NappDrawer Module. I am unable to debug the issue. As I see in the log it says the Error at when setting centerWindow in Drawer. I tried different different flow to solve that issue but unable to solve that.
Below is the Crash log for that.

```
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: view
CoreSimulator 581.2 - Device: iPhone XS Max - Runtime: iOS 12.1 (16B91) - DeviceType: iPhone Xs Max

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000107c39d8b objc_msgSend + 11
1   com.qalbit.feestbeesten         0x0000000102565ade -[MMDrawerController setCenterViewController:animated:] + 560
2   com.qalbit.feestbeesten         0x000000010255fbac -[DkNappDrawerDrawer setCenterWindow_:] + 668
3   com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x0000000106479700 DoProxyDelegateChangedValuesWithProxy + 626
4   com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x000000010647d133 -[TiProxy replaceValue:forKey:notification:] + 719
5   com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x00000001064577bb -[TiViewProxy setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 212
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x0000000104672de4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
7   com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x0000000106439166 -[KrollObject setValue:forKey:] + 432
8   com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x0000000106436fb0 KrollSetProperty + 421
9   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028fc0a5 JSC::JSCallbackObject<JSC::JSDestructibleObject>::put(JSC::JSCell*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::PropertyName, JSC::JSValue, JSC::PutPropertySlot&) + 277
10  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000102e8938a llint_slow_path_put_by_val + 1322
11  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028cd553 llint_entry + 15063
12  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028d02e2 llint_entry + 26726
13  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028d02e2 llint_entry + 26726
14  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028d02e2 llint_entry + 26726
15  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001028c98fe vmEntryToJavaScript + 244
16  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000102dc5846 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 470
17  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x0000000102fc69b4 JSC::profiledCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::ProfilingReason, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 196
18  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00000001029092d4 JSObjectCallAsFunction + 468
19  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x00000001064543e2 __TiBindingEventProcess_block_invoke + 53
20  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x000000010645430a TiBindingEventProcess + 723
21  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x0000000106475df5 -[KrollContext invoke:] + 109
22  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x0000000106475e68 -[KrollContext enqueue:] + 93
23  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x000000010647da91 TiBindingRunLoopEnqueue + 82
24  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x000000010645c896 -[TiViewProxy fireEvent:withObject:propagate:reportSuccess:errorCode:message:] + 224
25  com.appcelerator.TitaniumKit    0x000000010647c060 -[TiProxy fireEvent:withObject:] + 72
26  com.qalbit.feestbeesten         0x000000010255149e -[TiUIListView fireClickForItemAtIndexPath:tableView:accessoryButtonTapped:] + 1390 (TiUIListView.m:2248)
27  com.qalbit.feestbeesten         0x000000010254e3ea -[TiUIListView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 74 (TiUIListView.m:1835)
28  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114d4bdfd -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1813
29  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114d4c018 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
30  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114b320d2 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
31  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114b20b2c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 384
32  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114b4fefc _afterCACommitHandler + 135
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000108ce3c27 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000108cde0be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
35  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000108cde751 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
36  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0000000108cdde11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
37  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x000000010da471dd GSEventRunModal + 62
38  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x0000000114b2681d UIApplicationMain + 140
39  com.qalbit.feestbeesten         0x000000010234f07c main + 1004 (main.m:66)
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000010b0da575 start + 1



Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000004  rbx: 0x000000010258f911  rcx: 0x00000000000fc080  rdx: 0x0000000000000303
  rdi: 0x00007ff057731020  rsi: 0x000000011c23979a  rbp: 0x00007ffeed8bc5b0  rsp: 0x00007ffeed8bc528
   r8: 0x0000000000000036   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0xa000000000000000  r11: 0x000000011c23979a
  r12: 0x00007ff057869600  r13: 0x0000000107c39d80  r14: 0x00007ff05759d530  r15: 0x00007ff057731020
  rip: 0x0000000107c39d8b  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000104f2b000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     13
```

Comment: there is already a ticket for this issue: https://github.com/viezel/NappDrawer/issues/213 but no solution yet. I'm still using https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu which works fine in Ti 8.0.0

Comment: @miga Anyone maintains the NappDrawer Module?

Comment: I don't know, it is not my repo. But it is open source, so you could maintain it or add a fix :-)